# Electron + Angular 2 + node-serialport

Tags: angular, electron, node-serialport

I'm building an application with Electron + Angular 2 and the application needs to load the node-serialport but I'm having some problems when I'll to load these modules together.

For example, when I run my app with Electron + Angular 2 and without node-serialport, it works normally, but if I load with node-serialport whole application does not works correctly, my Angular 2 simply stop his features as binding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use electron, node-serialport and react, but i think it's the same root problem: electron and native-modules. I just posted a [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254287/electron-and-serial-ports/42591700#42591700) for a similar electron+node-serialport question. in summary:

You need to rebuild serialport for the version of node that electron expects, which is likely different from the version of node you have install globally. [electron-rebuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-rebuild) will help with the rebuild, but at last check you needed to delete the default build artifacts, otherwise electron-rebuild will not generate new ones.