# Building Electron with Ionic2, serialport, and electron-builder

Tags: ionic2, electron, electron-builder, node-serialport

I'm not sure which of the platforms / tools is the root of my problem so asking this question on SO rather than the issues of one of the Git-Hub repositories. I'm trying to develop a project based on [Polyonic](https://github.com/paulsutherland/Polyonic). Polyonic itself is a kind of seed mashup of Electron and Ionic2. My project also uses [node-serialport](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport), which is a Native Module.

My development versions are:
 - Node 7.4.0
 - Electron 1.6.10

... and running `ionic info` in the src folder of my project gives:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
    Gulp CLI         : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-gulp          : 1.0.1
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
    Cordova Platforms               : browser 4.1.0
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:

    Node       : v7.4.0
    OS         : Linux 4.6
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 4.0.5
```

If I do `npm install` in the src directory, then `npm install` in the root directory, the `npm start` in the root directory (which runs a gulp script in the Polyonic seed that bundles the Ionic project), the project launches and runs perfectly, no problems with node-serialport.

If I then build an executable by running `electron builder` in the root of my project, and then run the executable, in the Chrome DevTools console, I get this output:

```
Uncaught Error: The module '/home/vic/git/MyProject/build/node_modules/serialport/build/Release/serialport.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 53. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or`npm install`).
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (/home/vic/git/MyProject/build/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vic/git/MyProject/build/node_modules/serialport/lib/bindings.js:3:35)
```

I recognize that there are [other related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254287/electron-and-serial-ports/42591700#42591700) on SO that suggest using `electron-rebuild` to ensure the native modules are built against the version of node expected by Electron. But if I go into the project src folder, then run:

```
rm -rf node_modules/serialport/build/* 
node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -w serialport -f
```

... then go back into my project root folder and run `npm start` (it runs normally as before), then run `electron-builder` and run the executable, in the Chrome DevTools console, I get this output:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'serialport'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/tmp/.mount_7laJTZ/usr/bin/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418)
    at Module.require (module.js:498)
    at require (internal/module.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:73788)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:72414)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:111408)
```

This feels farther from working than I was before doing the `electron-rebuild` thing. Where am I going wrong? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will send me project in next hour, I will investigate what's wrong. You don't need to use electron-rebuild — electron-builder rebuilds automatically. (I am electron-builder maintainer.)

Comment: Whoa cool, I've just added you as a collaborator on the (private) github repo... have a look at the serial-service branch... you can chat me on freenode handle vicatcu if you want

Comment: You might already know this, but perusing the node-serialport repo issues for native and electron reveals a lot of confusion in userland. I have been able to successfully build the trivial project: https://github.com/johnny-five-io/electron-serialport

Comment: Please contact me using slack direct messages (https://slackin.electron.build/). Not clear how to use freenode :)

Comment: See my self-answer for details on what we did to get it working

Answer (score 2):

After working through it offline with @develar, we were able to solve the problem. I'm posting back here and accepting his answer to give credit where credit is due.

[This PR](https://github.com/paulsutherland/Polyonic/pull/9/files) to the Polyonic project is a direct result. In my estimation, the key change, however, was modifying the build block of the root package.json to:

```
"build": {
  "appId": "YOUR.APPID.GOES.HERE",
  "directories": {
    "app": "build"
   }
},
```

... and making sure that electron was in the devDependencies section rather than the dependencies section.

The key point here is that Polyonic, when you run `npm start` bundles everything up and puts it into a build folder in the root of your project. Then it runs `cd build && electron .` to run launch project. According to the electron-builder docs:

> - directories
>
>   - buildResources = build String - The path to build resources.
>   - output = dist String - The output directory.
>   - app String - The application directory (containing the application package.json), defaults to app,
>       www or working directory.

... so setting build.directories.app to 'build' tells electron builder to package the build directory, which is just what I needed.